# Angle between 2 points and vertical line

Tags: python, math, time, series, angle

For a few days I'm struggling to find the angle between 2 points and a vertical line. I've tried many answers which I found here but it seems that I'm doing something wrong because none of it it's working for me.
I have a series data with the actual value of buyers and sellers and for example when the buyers amount increases/decreases by let say 300 the angle between a vertical line and the current segment(previous point and current point) should be higher/lower then when the value increases/decreases by 20. When I calculate the angle the values are odd because for 300 I have: 0.19098522435968743 and for 20 I have: 2.8624052261117474.

The function which I'm using at the moment is:

```
deltaY = 20
deltaX = 1
angleInDegrees = math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY) * 180 / math.pi
```

I've tried also to calculate the angle between 2 lines and giving the x coordinate to the first one 0,0 but I get divide by zero error.

The plot looks like this:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X651Q.png)

And the data for longs and also shorts:
https://easyupload.io/pcxtym

I know that there are many questions/answers about this but I've tried everything I could find without no success.
Can anybody help?

To be more clear this is what I want to find out:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey6qv.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You are giving the context for the question which is nice. But the question itself is rather hard to understand. If you give the coordinates of two points, say what axe is vertical, say how exactly you compute the angle and what value you get, then we can try to say whether the result is correct or where a problem is.

Comment: I've added a link to an image with what I have calculated (with formula from post) and what I want. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Your arguments are in the wrong order: atan2(deltay, deltax) is correct.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/atan2-function-python/

Comment: When I change the order I have the angle = 89.8090 when the value is 300 andthe angle = 87.1375 when the value is 20. It's 90-previuous values.